# How to view built-in Firefox stylesheets?

Tags: css, firefox

I found instructions for how to do this in older versions, but I could find no way to **show the built-in stylesheets for Firefox 10.** A simple `locate *.css | grep -i 'mozilla\|firefox'` didn't reveal anything outside of my profile.

The reason I need this is because in Firefox links without a `href` attribute are styled like ordinary text, and I'd like them to be styled like links (I'm using [DataTables](http://datatables.net)). I'd like to copy all the Firefox styles (and nothing else) for `a` elements to ensure at least that all `a` elements (with or without `href`) look identical in all browsers.

Please note that *this is not a bug in DataTables*. In [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2):

> Authors may also create an A element that specifies no anchors, i.e.,
>   that doesn't specify href, name, or id. Values for these attributes
>   may be set at a later time through scripts.

In [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-a-element):

> If the a element has an href attribute, then it represents a hyperlink
>   (a hypertext anchor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `omni.ja/chrome/toolkit/res/html.css`

omni.ja is Zip archive inside Firefox installation directory.